# Inject constructor and companion object

Tags: java, junit, kotlin, guice, rx-kotlin

I'm kind of new to Kotlin and I'm trying to Inject a value (in this example it is just an Int but in the real code it is a Provider class)
What am I doing wrong here? and why is x is an unresolved reference?

```
class Test
@Inject constructor(private val x: Int) {

companion object {
    var y: Int = 0

        @BeforeClass @JvmStatic
        fun beforeClass() {
            y = x * 2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A companion object is a static object associated with a **class**, not with an instance of a class.

```
class Foo(val bar: Baz) {
    companion object {}
}
```

is similar to the following code in Java:

```
class Foo {
    static class Companion { }
    static final Foo.Companion Companion = new Foo.Companion();

    final Baz bar;
    Foo(Baz bar) { this.bar = bar; }
}
```

This is why `x` is not in the variable scope of the companion object, just like you cannot access the `bar` field from the static class `Companion`. Your property `y` is actually a field in the `Test.Companion` class.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `BeforeClass` thing, since I'm not familiar with it. Hope my answer helps anyway.